# Powershell HMAC (SHA256) - Error & Authorisation

Tags: powershell, hmac

Recently inherited a bit of a nightmare. Trying to get my head around saving an API to a text file for processing etc. I've landed on Powershell (open to other/better ideas) but I'm having trouble with the script itself and likely the Authorisation stuff (It's completely new to me!). There's very little in terms of instruction/examples from the source as well.

I may be overcomplicating this due to inexperience, most likely trying to learn at a more complicated point than I should.. Any and all learning material welcome!

The instructions;

> Produce a key for signing
>
> Produce a UTC timestamp string in the format “yyyyMMddTHHmmss”. If
> there is more than 10 minutes difference between this time and the pt
> servers time, the request will be rejected
>
> Generate a HMAC-SHA256 using your private key (as provided) and using
> the timestamp calculated above as the input.
>
> E.g. HMAC-SHA256({private key}, “20170217T133010”)
>
> Generate a HMAC-SHA256 using the previous HMAC as the key and the
> current API component (lowercase) plus your public key (lowercase), as
> the input.
>
> E.g. HMAC-SHA256({output from 1.2 above}, “keyword” + {public key})
>
> Sign the request
>
> Concatenate the following components to produce a single request
> string, using ‘|’ (ASCII 0x7D) as a separator (no new lines or
> spaces).
>
> HTTP Method (lowercase) Absolute path of the request URI (lowercase,
> excluding domain and query string, including initial forward slash)
> Content Length (for requests with no body, such as GET requests, 0
> (zero) should be provided). E.g.
> “get|/api/uat/places/v1.1/lh/public/properties|0”
>
> Calculate HMAC-SHA256 using the signing key produced from step 1 as
> the key and the request string generated in step 2.1 as the input.
>
> E.g. HMAC-SHA256({Signing Key}, {Request string})
>
> The output from 2.2 should then be Base64 encoded

My script

```
  #Variables
    $uri = "https://www.somewhere.com/api/uat/places/v1.1/lh/public/Properties"
    $method = "GET"
    $contentlength = "0"
    $seperator = "|"
    $timestamp = (Get-Date -format yyyyMMddTHHmmss).ToString()
    $component = "keyword"
    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    
    #api keys
    $apikey = "thisisthekey"
    $apisecretkey = "thisisthesecretkey"
    
    #request
    $requesttosign = $method.ToLower()+$seperator+$uri.ToLower()+$seperator+$contentlength
    
    #key
    #step1key
    $hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($apisecretkey)
    $step1key = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($timestamp))
    
    #step2key
    $hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($step1key)
    $step2key = $hmacsha1.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(($component+$apikey).ToLower()))


#signature
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($step2key)
$signature = $hmacsha3.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($requesttosign))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

$headers = @{
    Authorization = $signature
}

$data = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -Method $method -Headers $headers
$data | export-csv \\server\location\data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Error (Resolved)

```
Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.
At \\server\file.ps1:30 char:1
+ $signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodInvocationNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage
 
Invoke-RestMethod : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At \\server\file.ps1:36 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -Method $method -Headers $headers
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Error 2 (authentication)

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At \\sv-01-0013\DataProcesses\lifespan api\test 5.ps1:36 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -Method $method -Headers $headers
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: If I look at the error it seems like Contrained Language Mode is enabled for Powershell. Because of this you can't use most .NET methods (unless whitelisted or something, I'm not 100% familiar with using this mode)

Comment: Resolved error. Edited the registry to get around it. (will look at a permanent solution later)